# What does CFEXIT do inside a function in a CFC?

Tags: coldfusion

What does `<cfexit>` do inside a function, inside a cfc?

Is it the same as `<cfabort>`?

I'm refactoring some legacy code, and wonder if I need to pay special attention to it...

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My recollection of how a basic `<cfexit>` behaves is:

1. Used within a CFC, `cfexit` exits the cfc function. But
   processing of the calling page continues.
2. If within a function, but NOT inside a cfc, then processing is aborted.

---

**Update:** 
I just confirmed that behavior under CF9.0.1

Results (using cfexit)

```
Start calling page 
Called test()
Finish calling page 
Called on requestEnd
```

Results (using cfabort)

```
Start calling page 
Called test()
Called on requestEnd
```

---

**Test.cfm**

```
Start calling page <br />
<cfset createObject("component", "Foo").test()>
Finish calling page <br />
```

**Foo.cfc**

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="test" output="true">
        Called test()<br />
        <cfexit>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: ok, so it is behaving like `<cfreturn>` and if `returntype` is not `void`, it will throw exception.

Comment: Just use return. Great question. Silly tag :)

Comment: @Sergii - (merged) I think Aaron just meant silly in this context ;) But supporting your point, yes cfexit has all kinds of super powers cfreturn does not ;-) http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_d-e_19.html